# Error while logging into phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysqli

When I am using my godaddy account to login to my database, I am getting this error:

```
Error
#1135 - Can't create a new thread (errno 11); if you are not out of available memory, you can consult the manual for a possible OS-dependent bug
```

I am also getting this error when I try to connect to my data base. It used to work fine, but I added another table then I started getting this error. I think I messed up somewhere while creating the table. How can I fix this problem ? phpmyadmin is not letting me login.

Comment: I suggest contacting goDaddy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact Godaddy helpdesk.

As a workaround, you can try uploading PHP script which deletes the corresponding database, then navigating to that PHP from the browser. It gets executed and eliminates the data table... but you won't get any closer to knowing what was the real problem.